# Ajax call not running onKeydown

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have this ajax call that's suppose to run when a key is pressed on a specific textbox. Once in the call, it runs a function that fires an alert. But, its doesn't work. Maybe it's cause I wrote the call using an old forum post as reference. Assume, I called the jquery library cause on my test I did but I didn't post it here.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
<script>
       $("#<% =tb.ClientID%>").keydown
        (
            function ()
            {
                debugger; alert("hello");
            }
        );
</script>

<body>

   <asp:TextBox Id = "tb" runat = "server"/>

</body>
```

I'm new to these kind of calls. I'm very familiar with js functions, but I've never done this. Any explanations and suggestions, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code tries to select an element that doesn't exist at the time that the code runs.

Comment: Move your script to the bottom of the `body` or wrap it in a DOM ready statement. As it stands now, your script executes before the element with ID `tb` has been loaded on the page.

Comment: @tymeJV That makes sense, I'll try something out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML is processed line by line. So when it processes the contents of that `script` tag, it hasn't yet processed anything further down, such as the `body` tag or its contents.

Inside the `script`, you're running `$("#<% =tb.ClientID%>")`. It'll try to find an element by its ID, but since the `body` hasn't been processed yet, it will yield no results. With no results, it has nothing on which to set the listener for `.keydown`.

It's in cases like these that using jQuery's `$(document).ready` function or its equivalents becomes incredibly important and crucial to the code. `$(document).ready` accepts a function, and it will wait until the DOM is fully loaded before executing that code. So putting `$("#<% =tb.ClientID%>").keydown....` inside of a `$(document).ready` will ensure that the element has a chance to enter the DOM before the `.keydown` listener is attached to it.

You can find the docs for `$(document).ready()` [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

Comment: Should it be something like this `$(document).ready(("#<% =tb.ClientID%>").keydown(function(){});` ?

Comment: @JoséCorretjer-Gómez -- Close, DOM ready takes a function, then your code goes inside that - `$(document).ready(function() { //YOUR HANDLERS HERE });`

Comment: @tymeJV Sorry to be a bother. I tried it but it's still not working. This is what I wrote `$(document).ready
            (
                function ()
                {
                    $("#<% =tb.ClientID%>").keydown
                        (
                            function ()
                            {
                                debugger; alert("hello");
                            }
                        );
                }
             );`

Comment: Is it returning the right element? If you manually try to find the element by that id, does it return anything?

Comment: I managed to solve it. But I completely changed my approach so I didn't post anything but, I'll mark us as an answer for the sake of it :P